# Cannot set DataType in HierarchicalDataTemplate

Tags: c#, xml, wpf

When I set the DataType:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type xs:complexType}">
```

I get the following error:
The name "complexType" is not present in the namespace "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"

Comment: Search following schema for complex to see the acceptable types : https://www.w3.org/2009/XMLSchema/XMLSchema.xsd

Comment: It is in there. I have also changed the namespace, but it doesent help:        `xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2009/XMLSchema"`

Answer (score 0):

According to [MSDN DataTemplate.DataType Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate.datatype(v=vs.110).aspx)

> If this property targets an XML element that is not in the default
>   namespace, you must precede the element name with the namespace or a
>   namespace designator. For XML exposed through LINQ for XML, the
>   namespace appears in braces, preceded by a brace escape sequence: XAML
>
> ```
> <DataTemplate DataType="{}{http://myNamespace}Details">
> ```
>
> For XML exposed through XPath, the element name is preceded by a
>   namespace designator established by an instance of
>   XmlNamespaceMapping: XAML
>
> ```
> <DataTemplate DataType="mn:Details">
> ```

So please try `DataType="xs:complexType"` and `DataType="{}{xs}complexType"` for starters (don't declare `xs` as some `xmlns`).

*I'm not completely sure if this will work for you, but its definitely worth a try.*

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution: My company policy prevents VS from accessing the internet. No wonder it could not find the datatype.

Comment: So, do you expect the error would not be there if you have internet access (did it work on some development machine)?

Comment: Typically, whatever you enter in the xmlns definition, needs to match a name that is defined in an assembly that's referenced by your Project. I don't get how this is related to the internet connection.

Comment: You are right - the error still remains. The internet connection was not the problem. Do you know how I can restrict the hierarchicaldatatemplate to work only on certain nodes of my XML file? It is an XSD Schema document that I want to display.